# Python class variable getting changed after method ends for not applying deepcopy to list

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

Was trying to solve this leetcode question in python using backtracking -

```
Given a string s, partition s such that every substring of the partition is a palindrome. 
Return all possible palindrome partitioning of s.
```

Getting weird output for this solution -

```
class Solution:
    
    a = list()

    def backtrack(self, start, string, palindrome, stack):

        if start == len(string):
            self.a.append(stack)
            return
        if start == len(string)-1:
            stack.append(string[start])
            self.a.append(stack)
            stack.pop()
            return

        for end in range(start, len(string)):
            if start == end:
                stack.append(string[start])
                self.backtrack(start+1, string, palindrome, stack)
                stack.pop()

            elif string[start] == string[end] and ((end == start+1) or palindrome[start+1][end-1]):
                stack.append(string[start:end+1])
                palindrome[start][end] = True
                self.backtrack(end+1, string, palindrome, stack)
                stack.pop()

    def partition(self, string):
        stack =  []
        self.a.clear()
        palindrome = [[False for __ in range(len(string))] for _ in range(len(string))]
        for i in range(len(string)):
            palindrome[i][i] = True
        self.backtrack(0, string, palindrome, stack)
        return self.a
```

Input: `aab`

Output :

```
[[],[]]
```

This code works, just changed `list` to `set` and made other minor changes

```
class Solution:
    
    a = set()

    def backtrack(self, start, string, palindrome, stack):

        if start == len(string):
            if ",".join(stack) not in self.a:
                self.a.add(",".join(stack))
            return
        if start == len(string)-1:
            stack.append(string[start])
            if ",".join(stack) not in self.a:
                self.a.add(",".join(stack))
            stack.pop()
            return

        for end in range(start, len(string)):
            if start == end:
                stack.append(string[start])
                self.backtrack(start+1, string, palindrome, stack)
                stack.pop()

            elif string[start] == string[end] and ((end == start+1) or palindrome[start+1][end-1]):
                stack.append(string[start:end+1])
                palindrome[start][end] = True
                self.backtrack(end+1, string, palindrome, stack)
                stack.pop()

    def partition(self, string):
        stack = answer = []
        palindrome = [[False for __ in range(len(string))] for _ in range(len(string))]
        for i in range(len(string)):
            palindrome[i][i] = True
        self.backtrack(0, string, palindrome, stack)
        ans = [item.split(",") for item in self.a]
        self.a.clear()
        return ans
```

Input: `aab`

Output: `[["a","a","b"],["aa","b"]]`

Question : https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I have to apply `copy.deepcopy` while appending `stack` in the first code.

```
from copy import deepcopy

a = list()

def backtrack(self, start, string, palindrome, stack):

    if start == len(string):
        dc = deepcopy(stack)
        self.a.append(dc)
        return
    if start == len(string)-1:
        stack.append(string[start])
        dc = deepcopy(stack)
        self.a.append(dc)
        stack.pop()
        return
```

In python copy of a list doesn't make a new object always. For example -

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> x = l
>>> del l[1]
>>> l
[1, 3, 4]
>>> x
[1, 3, 4]
```

In the above code, `x and l` point to the same list

On using `copy.deepcopy` , a new list is created -

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> x = deepcopy(l)
>>> del l[1]
>>> l
[1, 3, 4]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Python lists perform differently. So, if I remove deepcopy, I will get empty lists as stack is getting popped totally at the end. Just learned this.

Comment: Pretty new to python. So, facing a bunch of issues

Answer (score 2):

- Here is similarly a Depth First Search Solution with less statements:

```
class Solution:
    def partition(self, s):
        res = []
        self.depth_first_search(s, [], res)
        return res

    def depth_first_search(self, s, path, res):
        if not s:
            res.append(path)
            return
        for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
            if self.is_palindrome(s[:i]):
                self.depth_first_search(s[i:], path + [s[:i]], res)

    def is_palindrome(self, s):
        return s == s[::-1]


print(Solution().partition("aab"))
```

Comment: Yeah, methods are called internally and not shown. Thanks, your solution is very elegant.